# php form values not showing

Tags: php, forms

My form won't show the values unless I add them to the required = array and not everything is required. So the firname, lasname, and email will show in the email that's sent but it won't show the phone and message (I have other fields to add too).

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['email'];

//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]{2,}"."$",$email )){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}

if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
    $values = array('firname','lasname','email','phone','message');
    $required = array('firname','lasname','email',);

    $your_email = "aasdasd@email.com";
    $email_subject = "Reservations Form: ".$_POST['subject'];
    $email_content = "new reservation:\n";

    foreach($values as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($value,$required)){
            if ($key != 'subject' && $key != '') {
                if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
            }
            $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
        }
    }

    if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/test/reservation-submission.html');
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}
?>`

<form action="reservations.php" method="post" id="contactform">
      <ol>
        <li><label>First Name *</label>
          <input id="firname" name="firname" class="text" value="" />
        </li>
         <li><label>Last Name *</label>
          <input id="lasname" name="lasname" class="text" value="" />
        </li>
        <li><label>Email *</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" class="text" type="email" value="" />
        </li>
        <li><label>Phone Number *</label>
          <input id="phone" name="phone" class="text" value="" />
        </li>
        <li><label>Best Time To Call</label>
          <select name="best time to call" id="call" class="drop">
        <option selected="selected" value="Morning">Morning</option>
        <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
        <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
                </select>
        </li>
        <br />
        <li><label>Age</label>
          <select name="age" id="age" class="drop">
        <option selected="selected" value="25+">25+</option>
        <option value="21-24">21-24</option>
                </select>
        </li>
        <br />
        <li> <label> Rental *</label>
        <select name="rental" id="rental" class="drop">
        <option selected="selected" value="12 Passenger Van">12 Passenger Van</option>
        <option value="15 Passenger Van">15 Passenger Van</option>
        <option value="Cargo Van">Cargo Van</option>
                </select> </li>
                <br />
                <li> <label> Pick up Location *</label>
        <select name="location" id="location" class="drop">
        <option selected="selected" value="Select Location">Select Location</option>
        <option value="U-Save JFK">U-Save JFK</option>
        <option value="U-Save LGA">U-Save LGA</option>
                </select> </li>
                <br />
        <li><label>Estimated Mileage</label>
        <select name="mileage" id="mileage" class="drop">
        <option selected="selected" value="Under 100">Under 100</option>
        <option value="100-500">100-500</option>
        <option value="500+">500+</option>
                </select>
        </li>
        <br />
        <li><label>Pick Up Date *</label>
          <input id="pick-up-date" name="pick-up-date" class="date" value="MM/DD/YY" /> <a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar1')"><img class="cal" align="absmiddle" src="cal/cal.gif" border="0" alt="Calendar"></a> 
        </li>
        <br />
        <li><label>Pick Up Time *</label>
          <select class="drop" name="pick up time" id="Pick Up Time">
    <option value="12:00 am">12:00 am</option> <option value="12:30 am">12:30 am</option>
    <option value="01:00 am">01:00 am</option> <option value="01:30 am">01:30 am</option>
    <option value="02:00 am">02:00 am</option> <option value="02:30 am">02:30 am</option>
    <option value="03:00 am">03:00 am</option> <option value="03:30 am">03:30 am</option>
    <option value="04:00 am">04:00 am</option> <option value="04:30 am">04:30 am</option>
    <option value="05:00 am">05:00 am</option> <option value="05:30 am">05:30 am</option>
    <option value="06:00 am">06:00 am</option> <option value="06:30 am">06:30 am</option>
    <option value="07:00 am">07:00 am</option> <option value="07:30 am">07:30 am</option>
    <option value="08:00 am">08:00 am</option> <option value="08:30 am">08:30 am</option>
    <option value="09:00 am">09:00 am</option> <option value="09:30 am">09:30 am</option>
    <option value="10:00 am">10:00 am</option> <option value="10:30 am">10:30 am</option>
    <option value="11:00 am">11:00 am</option> <option value="11:30 am">11:30 am</option>
    <option value="12:00 pm">12:00 pm</option> <option value="12:30 pm">12:30 pm</option>
    <option value="01:00 pm">01:00 pm</option> <option value="01:30 pm">01:30 pm</option>
    <option value="02:00 pm">02:00 pm</option> <option value="02:30 pm">02:30 pm</option>
    <option value="03:00 pm">03:00 pm</option> <option value="03:30 pm">03:30 pm</option>
    <option value="04:00 pm">04:00 pm</option> <option value="04:30 pm">04:30 pm</option>
    <option value="05:00 pm">05:00 pm</option> <option value="05:30 pm">05:30 pm</option>
    <option value="06:00 pm">06:00 pm</option> <option value="06:30 pm">06:30 pm</option>
    <option value="07:00 pm">07:00 pm</option> <option value="07:30 pm">07:30 pm</option>
    <option value="08:00 pm">08:00 pm</option> <option value="08:30 pm">08:30 pm</option>
    <option value="09:00 pm">09:00 pm</option> <option value="09:30 pm">09:30 pm</option>
    <option value="10:00 pm">10:00 pm</option> <option value="10:30 pm">10:30 pm</option>
    <option value="11:00 pm">11:00 pm</option> <option value="11:30 pm">11:30 pm</option>
        </select>
        </li>
        <br />
        <li><label>Drop Off Date *</label>
          <input id="drop-off-date" name="Drop Off Date" class="date" value="MM/DD/YY" /> <a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar2')"><img class="cal" align="absmiddle" src="cal/cal.gif" border="0" alt="Calendar" /></a> 
        </li>
        <br />
        <li><label>Drop Off Time *</label>
          <select class="drop" name="Drop Off Time" id="Drop Off Time">
    <option value="12:00 am">12:00 am</option> <option value="12:30 am">12:30 am</option>
    <option value="01:00 am">01:00 am</option> <option value="01:30 am">01:30 am</option>
    <option value="02:00 am">02:00 am</option> <option value="02:30 am">02:30 am</option>
    <option value="03:00 am">03:00 am</option> <option value="03:30 am">03:30 am</option>
    <option value="04:00 am">04:00 am</option> <option value="04:30 am">04:30 am</option>
    <option value="05:00 am">05:00 am</option> <option value="05:30 am">05:30 am</option>
    <option value="06:00 am">06:00 am</option> <option value="06:30 am">06:30 am</option>
    <option value="07:00 am">07:00 am</option> <option value="07:30 am">07:30 am</option>
    <option value="08:00 am">08:00 am</option> <option value="08:30 am">08:30 am</option>
    <option value="09:00 am">09:00 am</option> <option value="09:30 am">09:30 am</option>
    <option value="10:00 am">10:00 am</option> <option value="10:30 am">10:30 am</option>
    <option value="11:00 am">11:00 am</option> <option value="11:30 am">11:30 am</option>
    <option value="12:00 pm">12:00 pm</option> <option value="12:30 pm">12:30 pm</option>
    <option value="01:00 pm">01:00 pm</option> <option value="01:30 pm">01:30 pm</option>
    <option value="02:00 pm">02:00 pm</option> <option value="02:30 pm">02:30 pm</option>
    <option value="03:00 pm">03:00 pm</option> <option value="03:30 pm">03:30 pm</option>
    <option value="04:00 pm">04:00 pm</option> <option value="04:30 pm">04:30 pm</option>
    <option value="05:00 pm">05:00 pm</option> <option value="05:30 pm">05:30 pm</option>
    <option value="06:00 pm">06:00 pm</option> <option value="06:30 pm">06:30 pm</option>
    <option value="07:00 pm">07:00 pm</option> <option value="07:30 pm">07:30 pm</option>
    <option value="08:00 pm">08:00 pm</option> <option value="08:30 pm">08:30 pm</option>
    <option value="09:00 pm">09:00 pm</option> <option value="09:30 pm">09:30 pm</option>
    <option value="10:00 pm">10:00 pm</option> <option value="10:30 pm">10:30 pm</option>
    <option value="11:00 pm">11:00 pm</option> <option value="11:30 pm">11:30 pm</option>
        </select>
        </li>
        <br />

        <li><label>Additional Infomation</label>
          <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li class="button1">
          <input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField" src="images/reserve-now-btn.png" class="send" />
          <div class="clr"></div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed a `{` at the wrong location, which results in the non-required field being ignored all together.

```
foreach($values as $key => $value){
  if(in_array($value,$required)){
    if ($key != 'subject' && $key != '') {
      if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
    }
  } // <- Good
  $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
//  } <- Wrong
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just had to move that } down and it worked. /sigh

Answer (score 3):

Change this section:

```
foreach($values as $key => $value){
  if(in_array($value,$required)){
    if ($key != 'subject' && $key != '') {
      if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
    }
    $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
  }
}
```

to...

```
foreach($values as $key => $value){
  if(in_array($value,$required)){
    if ($key != 'subject' && $key != '') {
      if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
    }
  }
  $email_content .= $value) .': '.$_POST[$value])."\n";
}
```

To oversimplify, you are taking each item in your `$values` array and searching for it in the form. If it is in the `$required` list, then you check if it is blank. If it is blank, then it shows an error message. Otherwise, you want to add it to the message that will be sent by mail (`$email_content`).

Previously, the "add it to the email content" part was only executed within the "if it is required" loop. I moved it down, so that it is a part of the "for each `value` loop.

Comment: I would also suggest that you either use an IDE with auto-formatting or write your if-else statements on multiple lines, instead of writing it on one line. This makes your code more readable and makes errors like these easier to spot.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It helped a lot. I'm a noob at PHP and I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You should move out the `$email_content` part from the `if(in_array($value,$required)){` clause. One level up:

```
foreach($values as $key => $value){
   if(in_array($value,$required)){
     if ($key != 'subject' && $key != '') {
       if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
     }
     // from here
   }
   $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";  // to here
}
```

Because you want not only required fields to be added to the contents

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It worked and now I can enjoy the rest of my night. Lol!

Comment: Dede: why do you mark the last posted equal answer as your suggested answer? Either mark mine (that was first) or the a bit more detailed one by Cris - that is what I think.